# wifi is not detecting in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: networking, wireless

I installed ubuntu 14.04 in dell laptop, wifi is not detected.

i have installed wireless drivers also still it is not working.

It has BCM43224 driver and i installed it, In system settings on additional drivers tab it has shown this device is using an alternative drivere for wireless driver.

i checked in /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf, In that BCM43XXX is blacklisted and
b43,ssb is not blacklisted.

Please help me how to solve my issue. Thanks a lot

`lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` output is

```
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43224 802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:4353] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1520 Half-size Mini PCIe Card [1028:000e]
    Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge
```

rfkill list output is

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

`sudo apt purge bcmwl-kernel-source` 
with this command wifi is detected but internet is not working.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command.

Comment: Run `sudo apt purge bcmwl-kernel-source`, reboot and post the output of `rfkill list`.

Comment: It should be working. All looks OK. How do you now it is not working?

Comment: Try to run `sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer` and reboot. You need to be connected to the internet.

Comment: i tried some websites in firefox, they have not opened. They are opened in my mobile phone with the same wifi.

Comment: Did you disable your wired connection, when you tried the wireless?

Comment: i ran sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer, still internet is not working, I removed the usb cable (wired) and tried wireless

Comment: What about my previous question? If you disabled the wired connection, we can try another driver.

Comment: could you please tell me how to disable the wired connection thanks

Comment: You can do it in Network Manager the same place, where you connect the wireless.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and give details on what do you mean by "internet is not working". Can you connect to your router? Do you disable your wired connection, if any, when you test the wifi?

Comment: And what is the kernel version?

Answer (score 0):

You can try another driver. Connect to the internet and run

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

If you already installed it, you do not need to do it again. Switch to another driver by

```
sudo modprobe -r brcmsmac bcma
sudo modprobe b43
```

and test the Wi-Fi. Do not reboot! And do not forget to disable your wired connection when you test the wireless.

Comment: sudo modprobe -r brcmsmac bcma output is modprobe: FATAL: Module bcma is in use and wifi is not detecting now

Comment: What about the next command? And you need to disconnect first.

Comment: next command is executed but no output for the command, i disconnected and entered both commands again still wife is not detected

Comment: You never answered DID YOU DISABLE THE WIRED CONNECTION? It looks like your wireless connection is established with bcma OK. You can reboot now to get it back.

Comment: please tell me how to disable the wired connection, wifi is connected after rebooting the system and internet is not working. I will disable the wired connection and try the above commands, if you tell me how to disable it. Thanks

Comment: I told you already. Please edit your question and explain what you do in details. Do you have a wired connection to your router? How do you test the Wi-Fi?

Comment: i am using mobile tathering option and connecting the USB cable to laptop for getting wired connection, If i remove the USB cable then wifi is detected in the laptop which is a wireless connection now and testing the wifi by browing internet in firefox. Router has only wireless connection.

Comment: What do you mean by "detected"? Do you click the network name and actually connect to it?

Comment: If the wi-fi symbol in the laptop has some strength(some points high) then i guessed the wifi is detected, In wifi networks also it is shown as connected to network name

Comment: It looks like it IS connected. But you explain that very poorly. Detected and connected are different things. so what is the kernel version?

Comment: sorry for my poor explanation and i am new to ubuntu, kernel version is 3.13.0-107-generic

Comment: Maybe it is worth trying to upgrade the kernel to 4.4 by `sudo apt install linux-generic-lts-xenial`. But I am not sure that your Wi-Fi is not working now.

Comment: upgraded kernel to 4.4, Wi-Fi is not working